# Jupiter Project Not Making a Loop

Tags: python

I am currently making a **Basic Financial Budget** Follow Up for my college Data Science class but Im having trouble trying to make a loop. Currently the code works fine but it won't make the loop Im trying to make. I want the loop to end only while the selection is different to 5.

When I place the break under the `print("Thank You!")` Jupyter sends me an error which says that the break is out of the loop

When I remove the break I have after the while selection and run the code. It just allows me to write my OverallBudget and then prints 1-5 Infinitely. With the break It shows me just the 5 selections and works properly but ends the loop instead of sending me back to the selection menu.

Im a newbie and want to learn much more, maybe its a simple solution what I need but I've tried many solutions and am still having this problem.

```
def main(): 
    OverallBudget = int(input('Please State Your Current Overall Budget:'))
    
    def AddExpense(OverallBudget):
        Add_ExpenseAmount = int(input('Enter Expense Amount:'))
        Add_FrequencyExpense = int(input('Enter Monthly Frequency of the Expense:'))
        Add_OverallBill = Add_ExpenseAmount * Add_FrequencyExpense
        OverallBudget = OverallBudget - Add_OverallBill
        CheckBudget(OverallBudget)
        return OverallBudget 
    
    def SubstractExpense(OverallBudget):
        Sub_ExpenseAmount = int(input('Enter Expense Amount:'))
        Sub_FrequencyExpense = int(input('Enter Monthly Frquency of the Expense:'))
        Sub_OverallBill = Sub_ExpenseAmount * Sub_FrequencyExpense
        if Sub_OverallBill <= (OverallBudget): 
            OverallBudget = OverallBudget + Sub_OverallBill
            CheckBudget(OverallBudget)
        else:
             print('Please Re-Check the Amount Entered, it Cannot Exceed Overall Budget')
        return OverallBudget
    

    def AddRevenue(OverallBudget):
        Add_RevenueAmount = int(input('Enter Revenue Amount:'))
        OverallBudget = OverallBudget + Add_RevenueAmount 
        CheckBudget(OverallBudget)
        return OverallBudget
    

    def SubstractRevenue(OverallBudget):
        Sub_RevenueAmount = int(input('Enter Revenue Amount:'))
        OverallBudget = OverallBudget - Sub_RevenueAmount
        CheckBudget(OverallBudget)
        return OverallBudget
    

    def CheckBudget(OverallBudget):
        if OverallBudget >= 0:
            print('Your Overall Budget is:',OverallBudget)
        else: 
            print('You Exceeded Your Monthly Budget')
            print('Check your Expenses and Revenue')
            print('Current Balance',OverallBudget)
    

    selection = 0 
 
    while selection != 5: 
        print ('1 - Add Expenses')
        print ('2 - Remove Expenses')
        print ('3 - Add Revenue Stream')
        print ('4 - Remove Revenue Stream')
        print ('5 - End')
        break
              
  
    selection = int(input("State Your Input:"))
    
    if selection == 1:
        OverallBudget = AddExpense(OverallBudget)
    elif selection == 2: 
        OverallBudget = SubstractExpense(OverallBudget)
    elif selection == 3:
        OverallBudget = AddRevenue(OverallBudget)
    elif selection == 4:
        OverallBudget = SubstractRevenue(OverallBudget)
    elif selection == 5:
        print('Thank you!')
    else:
        print('Wrong Entry, Try Something Else:')

main()
```

Comment: If by loop you mean the 'While" construct, your break after the print('5 - end') line causes the while loop to terminate after printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong indentations and this makes all problem.

You should use `selection = ...` and all `if/else` inside `while` but you have it outside.

When you will have correct indentations then `break` put after `print('Thank you!')`

```
while selection != 5: 
    print ('1 - Add Expenses')
    print ('2 - Remove Expenses')
    print ('3 - Add Revenue Stream')
    print ('4 - Remove Revenue Stream')
    print ('5 - End')
  
    selection = int(input("State Your Input:"))
    
    if selection == 1:
        OverallBudget = AddExpense(OverallBudget)
    elif selection == 2: 
        OverallBudget = SubstractExpense(OverallBudget)
    elif selection == 3:
        OverallBudget = AddRevenue(OverallBudget)
    elif selection == 4:
        OverallBudget = SubstractRevenue(OverallBudget)
    elif selection == 5:
        print('Thank you!')
        break
    else:
        print('Wrong Entry, Try Something Else:')
```